# RSS API capable to add, delete, and list all RSS resources with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, rss, rss-reader

Good afternoon, I have to do a task that in principle it seemed easy.

The task is to create an API that allows you to list, add, and remove RSS sources, and fetch the last contents of the feeds. I also have to find a way for returning old content if the RSS source is offline.

I've done the Resource model and controller, the migration, and the WEB route (I know that i must put the routes in api.php, but i want to ensure by frontend that it returns all the data that I want and then I will test it with Postman), but I'm blocked because I don't know how to proceed now.

I leave the code below to you to understand what I'm doing:

web.php (api.php in a future):

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//Resource routes:
Route::get('/resources/{resource}', 'ResourcesController@show')
    ->name('resources.show');

Route::feeds();
```

ResourcesController.php:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Resource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResourcesController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request, Resource $resource)
    {
        return $resource;
    }
}
```

Resource.php:

```php
namespace App;

use Spatie\Feed\Feedable;
use Spatie\Feed\FeedItem;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resource extends Model implements Feedable
{
    public function toFeedResource()
    {
        return FeedItem::create()
        ->id($this->id)
        ->title($this->title)
        ->content($this->description)
        ->updated($this->updated_at)
        ->link($this->link)
        ->source($this->source);
    }

    public static function getResourceItems()
    {
        return static::all();
    }

    public function getLinkAttribute()
    {
        return route('resources.show', $this);
    }
}
```

create_resources_table.php:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('source');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Any help will be welcome, and thanks in advance.